# Use a COM interface from C#, that does not have fixed CLSID

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am using a third party library, that exposes a COM interface (always the same one). However, for whatever reason they decided to change the CLSID with every new version. I can find the CLSID in registry, or probably even from ProgID, but I need to use it from C#.

```
[ComImport, Guid("THAT-CHANGES")]
interface IFoo {
  void Bar();
}
```

I can basically declare otherwise identical IFooV1, IFooV2, etc, that would have different GUID, and do manual dispatch between them. However, I'd like to know if its possible to set that GUID at runtime after figuring out which version it is to avoid code duplication.

Comment: How do you get instances of objects that implement the interface? Or are you implementing the interface? You shouldn't need to annotate your copy of the interface with `[Guid]` because you aren't exporting the interface.

Comment: @Dai, ComImport is a part of the mechanism, that .NET Framework uses to use COM interfaces as .NET objects. GUID is required in this case to know which interface to map to.

Comment: Right, but how are you instantiating or getting the interface'd object?

Comment: @Dai, the method to get the instance does not matter, in the end with .NET Framework I get System.__ComObject, which I cast to the necessary interface defined like in the question. .NET Framework has a special cast implementation for that case, that performs the binding.

Comment: @Dai, right now I call int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppvObject) on the ImmersiveShell object (basically, I query another COM object to give me this one).

Comment: IID, not CLSID.  A programmer that creates a new version is required to change the guid, very, very important.  Getting a version mismatch is far nastier in COM than it is in .NET.  In .NET you'd typically get a TypeLoadException or MissingMethodException, no great joy, but in COM the corruption is far more serious.  An AccessViolationException only if you are lucky.  You'd have to give up on using the interface, assuming it supports IDispatch, use the *dynamic* keyword in C#.  And be ready for misery.  Don't do it is the only decent advice.